# Using the onEdit trigger with Google Sheets when importing for Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My job uses a google form to input information into a google sheet.  One of the inputs on the google sheet is the date of the entry from the google form (date shows in sheet in Column A).

I am trying to create a simple script that places a black border on the top portion of the cell range in the google sheet each time there is a new day. To do it, I tried to use two steps.  I created a column (column AM) at the end of the sheet with `=if(A561 = "", 0,day(A561))` in it.  Essentially, the column is set to all 0's until an entry is made in that line, and the value updates to the `day` value.  Then I wrote the following as seen below.  The process works on my test sheets, however in my test sheets I was not importing from a google form.

Final bit of information.  I do not believer there are any technically blank cells in the sheet that I am working in.  Every cell is set to a value of a different cell that comes from the google form.

Can anyone offer any help as to why my process is not working?

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var entries = [{name:"placeBorders", functionName:"placeBorders"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
   placeBorders();
};


//Will need to update the value of j every so often to maintain speed
function placeBorders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRowUsed = 0

for (var j = 525; j <= 10000; j++) {

if (mysheet.getRange(j, 39).getValue() == 0) {
  lastRowUsed = j - 1
  break;
 }

  } 

  if (mysheet.getRange(lastRowUsed, 39).getValue() !=     mysheet.getRange(lastRowUsed - 1, 39).getValue()) {
mysheet.getRange(lastRowUsed, 1, 1, 15).setBorder(true, null, null, null,     null, null);
 }


}
```

Comment: IMNO onEdit simple or installable triggers should not be used to add menus as it will run every time that a cell is edited. On the official documentation onOpen() is used.

Comment: Hmm, this is not too much of a problem because I have the two steps that need to occur (the script itself and the `if statement` in column AM).  That said, I commented out the `sheet.addMenu` line and it still appears to not be working.

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: No error.  Just does not work.  If I manually play the script it will work, but not when a cell updates.

Comment: There is no trigger for cell updates. To trigger a function when a user edit a cell, use the on edit simple or installable trigger. To trigger a function when a form submits a response, use the onSubmit installable trigger. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Answer (score 1):

The onEdit function does not have permission to create a menu. If you leave out sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries), then it will run placeBorders.

Comment: I appreciate it.  I will let this run a bit, and see how it turns out tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, does not seem to work.  I commented out the line in question, but still not working.

Comment: Run placeBorders independently from the google apps script and see what error you will get.